# Flutter PDFView is not scrolling inside Bottom sheet

Tags: flutter, pdf, scroll

```dart
  _bottomSheet(String remotePDFpath) {
    return showModalBottomSheet(
        context: context,
        isScrollControlled: true,
        isDismissible: true,
        builder: (context) {
          return DraggableScrollableSheet(
            minChildSize: 1,
            initialChildSize: 1,
            builder: (BuildContext context, ScrollController scrollController) {

              return Stack(
                children: <Widget>[
                  remotePDFpath.isNotEmpty
                      ? PDFView(
                        filePath: remotePDFpath,
                        enableSwipe: true,

                        swipeHorizontal: false,
                        autoSpacing: false,
                        pageFling: true,
                        pageSnap: true,
                        defaultPage: currentPage!,
                        fitPolicy: FitPolicy.BOTH,
                        preventLinkNavigation: false,

                        // if set to true the link is handled in flutter
                        onRender: (_pages) {
                          setState(() {
                            isReady = true;
                          });
                        },
                        onError: (error) {
                          setState(() {
                            errorMessage = error.toString();
                          });
                          print(error.toString());
                        },
                        onPageError: (page, error) {
                          setState(() {
                            errorMessage = '$page: ${error.toString()}';
                          });
                          print('$page: ${error.toString()}');
                        },
                        onPageChanged: (int? page, int? total) {
                          print('page change: $page/$total');
                          setState(() {
                            currentPage = page;
                          });
                        },
                      )
                      : errorMessage.isEmpty
                          ? !isReady
                              ? const Center(
                                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                                    color: Colors.black54,
                                  ),
                                )
                              : Container()
                          : Center(
                              child: Text(errorMessage),
                            ),
                ],
              );
            },
          );
        });
  }
```

Tried adding Single child scrollview and ListView. Both are creating "Object was given an infinite size during layout" issue